# Reduction of morphism with connected fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of notherian schemes over a DVR $R$, $Y$ being a smooth connected scheme. Assuming the generic fiber of $f_K:X_K\rightarrow Y_K$ to be connected (even smooth connected), where $K=Frac(R)$, is it true that the generic fiber of $f_k:X_k\rightarrow Y_k$ is also connected?
It seems that applying Stein factorization gives this result but I am not sure of my interpretation.

Comment: Is $f$ flat?  The result is not true if you allow $f$ to be non-flat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if $Y$ is proper and $f_K$ and $f_k$ generically smooth ?

Comment: A counterexample in the absence of flatness is when f is a disjoint union of two maps, one of which lies over the special fiber. (For instance, $f= Id_Y \cup Y_k \hookrightarrow Y$.) Then both $f_K$ and $f_k$ are smooth, while the special fiber is obviously disconnected.

Comment: Thank you. What if $X$ is connected?